# Variable in xsl:element

Tags: xslt

Let's say that I have got such variable defined in XSLT

```
 <xsl:variable name="groupedOrLinked">
   <xsl:choose> 
    <xsl:when test="Field[@key='X']='80'">Grouped</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="Field[@key='X']='00'">Linked</xsl:when>     
   </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:variable>
```

Is there any way to use this variable in `<xsl:element>` name attribute? The following line doesn't work:

```
<xsl:element name="$groupedOrLinked">
   ...
</xsl:element>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `{}` 
you should use

```
<xsl:element name="{$groupedOrLinked}">
[...]
</xsl:element>
```

Comment: Right! I forgot about braces.

Comment: +1 Correct answer: from http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates : _"Curly braces are not recognized in an attribute value in an XSLT stylesheet unless the attribute is specifically stated to be one that is interpreted as an attribute value template; in an element syntax summary, the value of such attributes is surrounded by curly braces."_ And from http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Creating-Elements-with-xsl:element : `<!-- Category: instruction --> <xsl:element name = { qname } namespace = { uri-reference } use-attribute-sets = qnames> <!-- Content: template --> </xsl:element>`